# Add Up and Down Votes in bootstrap

Tags: python, bootstrap-4

I am creating a website, where I want to implement Up and Down voting button. I am using Flask and Bootstrap for that. So, if anyone can tell me how to add up and down votes without using jQuery?
Bootstrap version is 4, so no glyphicons are available. Any help?

```
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">

                    {{{{Need those buttons here}}}}



           <div class="row" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                  <a href="#">{{posts[post]["user"]}} &nbsp;</a>
                  <em> {{posts[post]["title"]}} </em>
                </div>
             <div class="row" style="margin-left: 5px;">
              <a href="#">/user311 &nbsp;</a>
              <a target="_blank" href={{ posts[post]["replies"]["link"] }}>{{ posts[post]["replies"]["head"] }} </a>
            </div>

            </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: For the icons you could use Font Awesome: https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-down?style=solid https://fontawesome.com/icons/caret-up?style=solid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just link to a [font awesome CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css) and then add this to your `card-body` div:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x"></i></a>
</div>
```

**N.B.** Change **fa-2x** according to the size you want for the icon.

---

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9j0ggd5g/5/